# Adding another version of app in windows phone marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

Iam an newbie to windows phone. I had developed an simple application and i posted in            windows phone marketplace. After i posted my application has been accepted and published in the marketplace. But after some installation i found minor bug in my application.Now i changed and deployed. I don't know how to remove the old xap file and to upload this new xap file. Can anybody help me through this???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us and sign in
2. Go to **Dashboard**, then **Apps** and choose app you want to update
3. There is **Update app** link there

Comment: k,iam getting updated but it is again showing it will take 5 days to process the app when i click on submit. Will windows store again validate my application??

Comment: Yes, that's right. Another certification will be processed for every update.